# Instrumental variable

Tags: regression, econometrics, endogeneity

I am exploring the impact of social media WOM on firm performance during the 8 quarters of 2014-2015 for several firms. As WOM is likely endogenous, I was thinking of using weather data as instrument. The idea is that when, in a given quarter, the number of rainy days (or the number of days with above average precipitation) is higher, people stay at home more and are likely to, say, tweet more (relevance). Moreover, weather does not seem to directly impact firm performance (exclusion restriction).

My question is whether you think this can be a valid instrument. To be more specific, is it OK that the value of this instrument for any given quarter is identical for all firms in my sample?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site Ali. Could you clarify your question? What is WOM and what do you mean by weather data as instrument? Like as a predictor?

Comment: @André.B, instrument is a variable that helps obtain consistent estimators of regression coefficients in the presence of endogenous predictors (those that are correlated with unobserved factors affecting the dependent variable).

Comment: @AlexK trying to clean up the original question to conform with the suggestions from: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated. As stackexchange is a repository of questions and answers it needs to be clear for others and easily searchable

Comment: WOM means users' chatter on, say, Twitter. I am interested in studying how  people talking about a given firm on Twitter impacts the firm's performance (e.g. its stock price). In order to use weather, I will collect data regarding the number of rainy days during that time period (i.e. that quarter).

Comment: Can anyone please help with my question above?

Answer (score 1):

One of the assumptions of IV is that the instrument (weather) only effects the outcome (say sales revenue) through the WOM effect. I think that is a hard assumption to swallow in most contexts. For example, rain makes people stay at home and spend time watching TV or browsing the internet. This may lead to additional purchases because people are exposed to advertising or just because they do more shopping because the outside option is less attractive. This would violate the exclusion restriction.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dimitriy V. Masterov. If my outcome is "attitude towards the brand", is it safe to argue that weather does not directly impact attitude toward the brand? In that case, do you think it can potentially be a good instrument? My main concern is that it its value in each time period is identical for all firms in my sample. Do you think it can cause any issue?

Comment: I think it depends on the brand and how attitude is measured. If Burberry calls me on rainy day to gauge my opinion of their raincoats, would it be higher? Or if the attitude is measured via an email survey, does the rain change the composition of the responders, which alters the rating? I don't think the weather being the same is inherently a problem. Why does that make you worried?

Comment: Thanks @Dimitriy V. Masterov. The reason I was worried was that all of the IVs that I have seen in different papers had brand-specific amount of variation (they had different values for brand X  and brand Y in a given time period). So, based on what you say, the fact that the value of the IV is the same for all of the brands in a given time period is not problematic. Right?